# When and why did Joey and Rachel break up in Friends?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

I was watching Friends tv series season 10, where Joey and Rachel start dating. I got to see them dating, but afterwards, I couldn't find a break-up scene, just that they are friends.

Why did they break up?
When did they break up? (especially episode info will be good)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[According to the Wikia](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/Joey_and_Rachel):

> Joey and Rachel continue to date, but can't make it past kissing.
>   Every time Joey would slide his hand across Rachel's thigh, she would
>   slap it away, and Joey could not manage to get Rachel's bra open. This
>   is most likely due to the fact that Joey has tried many times to get
>   Rachel's bra off, and she got used to slapping it away; Rachel herself
>   notes that she was unable to stop herself thinking about the fact that
>   Joey was the one touching her.
>
> After trying again and injuring Joey,
>   the two decide that they are not compatible with each other. They
>   decide that they are too good as friends to pursue a romantic
>   relationship and leave it at that, their relationship returning to
>   normal.
>
> [...]
>
> They broke up in [The One With Ross' Tan](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_With_Ross%27_Tan) (S10E03)

The break-up is implied in the final scene. It starts out by them asking Chandler about his relationship with Monica ([source of this transcript](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/1003.shtml)):

> Rachel: Hi! Hey, listen, can we ask you a question? When you and
>   Monica first hooked up, was it weird going from friends to... more
>   than that?
>
> Chandler: Kinda... you know, sneaking around, having to hide from you
>   guys...
>
> Rachel: No, no, no... No, I mean... se-x-u-ally...
>
> Joey: Yeah, was there a part of you that... felt like it was... really
>   wrong?
>
> Chandler: Actually, no. No, it felt right. You know, it felt like
>   uhm... I can't believe we haven't been doing this the whole time.
>
> (Rachel and Joey are still looking at Chandler, slowly letting his
>   words get to them)
>
> Chandler: I can tell from your expressions that that's the good news
>   you were hoping for... Well, I'm gonna go continue to... spread the
>   joy.(Chandler leaves the apartment. Joey sighs)

They then apply this to their relationship:

> Rachel: Well, just because it happened that way for them doesn't mean
>   it has to happen that way for us.
>
> Joey: Yeah, yeah... Absolutely. I mean, just because something's
>   difficult doesn't mean that you quit.
>
> Rachel: Right, totally.
>
> Joey: Yeah, so we just keep trying and trying until we... do it.
>
> Rachel: Yeah, and if doesn't work, then we'll be just one of those
>   couples that never have sex.
>
> Joey: That's a... pla-an.

And that's the point where they realize their relationship doesn't work.

> (They both stare for a while, and then look at each other)
>
> Joey: (sighs) Wow... I did not see this coming.
>
> Rachel: I know.
>
> Joey: I don't get it. I mean, I was so sure this was what I wanted.
>
> Rachel: Hmmm... Me too...

They've resigned themselves to the failure.

> (She puts her head on Joey's shoulder and Joey kisses her on her
>   head.)
>
> Rachel: I wonder how Monica and Chandler could do it?
>
> Joey: I guess they weren't as good friends as we are.
>
> (Lifts her head from Joey's shoulder)
>
> Rachel: Aah... I bet you're right.

And then they finalize their break-up, without actually expressing it:

> (They look at each other for a while)
>
> Joey: So...
>
> Rachel: Yeah.

Comment: I went through that episode's script but can't find any mention of breakup

Comment: @AnkitSharma thats because it was implicit, not explicit. Some of the characters are much more about nuance and impression that others, who are in turn blunter.

Comment: `This is most likely due to the fact that Joey has tried many times to get Rachel's bra off...`  Yeah, one time he just *looked* at Monica's and it popped open!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about when, but why there are 2 reasons.

In universe - They decided they were too awkward as a couple, especially the sex part, and were better off as friends.

Out of universe - Matt Le Blanc was getting a spin off show and Jennifer Aniston wasn't going to be in it.

Answer (score 5):

**It was awkward for both of them.**

Rachel acts weird each time they started kissing, they had problems with Ross being okay with their relationship and deep down they felt always awkward, because they were friends who wouldn't do such a thing.

From [wikia](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/Joey_and_Rachel),

> Joey and Rachel continue to date, but can't make it past kissing.
>   Every time Joey would slide his hand across Rachel's thigh, she would
>   slap it away, and Joey could not manage to get Rachel's bra open. This
>   is most likely due to the fact that Joey has tried many times to get
>   Rachel's bra off, and she got used to slapping it away; Rachel herself
>   notes that she was unable to stop herself thinking about the fact that
>   Joey was the one touching her. After trying again and injuring Joey,
>   the two decide that they are not compatible with each other. They
>   decide that they are too good as friends to pursue a romantic
>   relationship and leave it at that, their relationship returning to
>   normal.

Further read : [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Friends-TV-series-When-exactly-did-Rachel-and-Joey-break-up-with-each-other) , [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/howyoudoin/comments/5tjwcc/real_reason_for_joey_and_rachels_break_up/)